# For which $p$ primes is $p^{p-1}$ a divisor of $(p-1)^p + 1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

$p = 2$ and $p = 3$ definitely are solutions. I think these are all the solutions, but how can I prove it?

Comment: Use [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to compute the reminder of what is left after diving by $p^2$

Answer (score 3):

We consider the given number $N(p) =(p-1)^p+1$ modulo $p^3$. In the following, $p$ is a prime $>3$. Using the binomial formula we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
N(p)&\equiv
1+
(-1)^p 
+ p\binom p1(-1)^{p-1}
+ p^2\binom p2(-1)^{p-2}
\\
&=
1+
(-1) 
+ p^2
- p^2\frac 12p(p-1)
\\
&=
p^2(\text{Number no divisible by $p$})\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: @rtybase... yes, did not see the comment, started it as an answer...

Answer (score 2):

According to [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) and assuming $p$-odd, thus $(-1)^p=-1$ and $(-1)^{p-1}=1$
$$(p-1)^p+1=\sum\limits_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k}p^k(-1)^{p-k}+1=\\
-1+\sum\limits_{\color{red}{k=1}}^p \binom{p}{k}p^k(-1)^{p-k} +1=p^2+\sum\limits_{\color{red}{k=2}}^p \binom{p}{k}p^k(-1)^{p-k}=\\
p^2\left(1+\sum\limits_{k=2}^p \binom{p}{k}p^{\color{red}{k-2}}(-1)^{p-k}\right)=...$$
also $\binom{p}{2}=\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$ so we can extract a $p$ from it, thus 
$$...=p^{\color{red}{2}}\left(1+p\cdot Q\right)$$
and the answer follows.